# Division of signed integers in assembly MIPS without div and divu

Tags: assembly, mips, division

How to divides two 4-byte signed integers in assembly MIPS without using `div` or `divu` with less complexity

Exemple:

```
Input:
   $a0 = -7
   $a1 = 2 

Output:
   lo = -3
   hi = -1
```

Comment: If you don't have (or don't want to use) a divide instruction, you need to do long division one bit at a time.

Comment: @old_timer I doubt that the OP wants to write a program that only works for the input `a1 = 2` and not for other values...

Answer (score 0):

Your quickest option is to use long division.

Remember that in grade school we would do long division with the positive version of the numbers then tack the sign(s) on after we were done.

No change here with signed numbers in base 2

If you were to do a straight -7/2 then FF..FFF9>>1 = FFF...FFFC which is -4 not -3
but if the number is considered signed then (~FF...FF9)+1 = 00...007; 7>>1 = 3; 7&1 = 1.  -3 r -1

If you wanted non-powers of two then long division is the initial choice.  You can search for other algorithms, long division is the easy one.

```
unsigned int xdiv ( int n, int d )
{
    unsigned int acc;
    unsigned int res;
    unsigned int sign;
    unsigned int remain;
    unsigned int ra;
    
    remain=0;
    sign=(n^d)&(1<<31);
    if(sign)
    {
        if(n&(1<<31)) 
        {
            n=-n;
            remain=sign;
        }
        if(d&(1<<31)) d=-d;
    }
    
    acc=0;
    res=0;
    
    if(d==0) return(1);
    for(ra=0;ra<32;ra++)
    {
        acc<<=1;
        acc|=(n>>31)&1;
        n<<=1;
        res<<=1;
        if(acc>=d)
        {
            res|=1;
            acc-=d;
        }
    }

    printf("----\n");
    if(sign) res=-res;
    if(remain) acc=-acc;
    printf("%u %u\n",res,acc);
    printf("%d %d\n",res,acc);
    printf("%X %X\n",res,acc);
    printf("----\n");
    
    return(0);
}
```

base 2 is simpler than base 10 the denominator can only go into the accumulated value zero times or one time, so you do not have to do extra work to figure out how many times (would be a simple subtract loop)

```
    if(acc>=d)
    {
        res|=1;
        acc-=d;
    }
```

Just like in grade school you start one digit/position at a time, how many times does the denominator divide into the accumulated/dropped down value?  In base 2 that is either 0 or 1 times so you save that 0 or 1 for that position, drop down the next bit, repeat is it zero or one times, drop down the next bit.  You keep accumulating bits in that dynamic value and comparing it to the denominator as you go, one bit dropped down for every bit added to the result.  Repeat for all the bits in the numerator.

I forgot than a remainder can be negative, thanks!